# Getting java IAIK PKCS11 wrapper work for nfast

Tags: java, cryptography, pkcs#11, hsm, nshield

I am trying to get IAIK PKCS11 wrapper to work with nfast.

It is always expecting pkcs11wrapper library file and throws an error -

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: pkcs11wrapper (Not found in java.library.path)

How do I get it to use the library file (`/opt/nfast/toolkits/pkcs11/libcknfast.so`) provided by the HSM?

Any help is greatly appreciated and forgotten about!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the path to the IAIK pkcs11wrapper, either on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, java.library.path (-Djava.library.path=java.library.path:/path/to/pkcs11wrapper) or via the iaik properties file using PKCS11_WRAPPER_PATH variable.

All are described in the IAIK documentation links below.

http://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Core-Crypto-Toolkits/PKCS_11_Provider/quick_start
http://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Core-Crypto-Toolkits/PKCS_11_Provider/installing

Andy